# Connect NiFi to Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, apache-nifi

I have no problem to connect Oracle 11g with Oracle SQL Developer with configuration below:

```
Username: orc
Password: PAP
Connection Type: Basic
Hostname: connect.gogo.com
Port: 1528
Service name: svcname
```

In NIFI, any idea how should I put the value for the Database Connection URL?

```
Database Connection URL:
Database Driver Class Name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Database Driver Location: /opt/nifi/jdbc/ojdbc8.jar
```

Thanks,
Kenny

Answer (score 2):

you can add a `DBCPConnectionPool` under `Controller Service` like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Database Connection URL:` `jdbc:oracle:thin:@connect.gogo.com:1528/svcname`

more information here

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html

or you could use tnsnames.ora file syntax in url like this:

`Database Connection URL:` `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=connect.gogo.com)(PORT=1528)))(CONNECT_DATA=...))`